# Protect IIS folder from being deleted by WebDeploy

Tags: asp.net, iis, webdeploy

I have a folder on my web application which is used to store user uploads, i.e. profile pictures, that sort of thing.

When I use WebDeploy, there is an option for "Leave extra files (Do not delete)" which when ticked makes sure that the profile pictures are not deleted.

What I am seeking is a way to ensure that even if that is unticked, a certain folder is safe from deletion. The reason for this being that I don't want another developer to accidentally disable the feature in future. Or me for that matter.

Any ideas? I have seen a few similar questions on here but nothing seems to be relevant to Visual Studio 2010, which is what I am using.

Comment: Have you tried excluding the folder?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158.aspx#can_i_exclude_specific_files_or_folders_from_deployment  I don't remember if this also makes sure that Web Deploy doesn't delete existing files in the folder.

Comment: What if you make that directory as virtual directory? Is it still deleted on wed deploy?

Answer (score 3):

(I assume you're using publish profiles as per Visual Studio 2010 w/ the Azure SDK or Visual Studio 2012 RTM. If you're not, create an MSBuild file called `ProjectName.wpp.targets` in the project root and put content in that instead)

You can disable all forms of deletes by setting `<SkipExtraFilesOnServer>true</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>` in your publish profile (equivalent to the checkbox you mentioned).

To skip a particular directory, a comment on this question implies you can use the following syntax:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment Include="FolderName" />
</ItemGroup>
```

But I've never seen that before and haven't tested it. Failing that, you can specify an explicit skip rule. "FolderName" is being skipped here - keep in mind that `AbsolutePath` is a regex:

```
<MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipFolderName">
  <SkipAction>Delete</SkipAction>
  <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
  <AbsolutePath>FolderName$</AbsolutePath>
</MsDeploySkipRules>
```

**NOTE:** There are [some scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576662/msdeploy-skip-rules-when-using-msbuild-publishprofile-with-visual-studio-2012) in which skip rules don't work when using Visual Studio unless you also set `UseMsDeployExe` to `true`

Comment: If I add `MsDeploySkipRules` to my publish file it complains about the `Include` attribute not being a valid attribute, if I remove it I can still publish but it doesn't honor the rule.

Comment: `MsDeploySkipRules` is an item, so it needs to be in an `ItemGroup`, rather than a `PropertyGroup`.

Comment: `Web deployment task failed. (Unrecognized skip directive 'skipaction'. Must be one of the following: "objectName," "keyAttribute," "absolutePath," "xPath," "attributes.<name>."`

Comment: @TheMuffinMan - Are you running Visual Studio 2010 by any chance? You might need to install SP1 + the latest Azure SDK

Comment: I'm using the latest version of 2013 and I'm not currently using Azure. This is for deploying to my test server (Amazon EC2)

Answer (score 2):

You can set specific rules on the target machines using the msdeploy.exe.configsettings file, there is also a msdeploy.exe.configsettings.example file in the same folder. The file is located in  %program files%\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy  - folder see [Web Deploy Rules](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd568992%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

You can set Rules and skipDirectives here and enable whether they are defaulted so you get your expected default behaviour.

Comment: Great idea! I always forget about that config file