# Visual Studio Publish stuck at Adding ACL's for path

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webdeploy

I'm trying to publish an web application but it's stuck for the last 10 minutes at `Adding ACL's for path`. I have no clue why it's stuck there, I published multiple times without a problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem and it turns out, that the web application that I deployed had accumulated lots of user-specific directories and files in a custom directory for uploads / report files / etc. Visual Studio checks and updates the ACLs for every file and directory and that is why it takes so long if there are many of them.

Check for directories with a huge amount of user-generated content or other content with lots of files and check if you can safely delete them (for example if those files are only created temporarily - like it had been the case here).

After cleaning up the directory on the web server the deployment is almost instant for incremental updates, which have been very slow before the cleanup process.

Comment: This is very similar to an issue I'm having. In my case, the files are important and I can't delete them. Do you know if there is any way to tell msdeploy certain directories to simply ignore?

Comment: @LelandRichardson I haven't checked but maybe you found an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576662/msdeploy-skip-rules-when-using-msbuild-publishprofile-with-visual-studio-2012

Comment: I spend few hours trying to debug this stupid thing, trying to see if someone was messing around with build definitions, with build server, with permissions etc. And at the end, look at that...just few extra files that crashes everything... Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 8):

It seems you have too many files and it takes to much time. I resolved same issue by adding following line to *.pubxml* file.

```
<IncludeSetACLProviderOnDestination>False</IncludeSetACLProviderOnDestination>
```

Comment: You should elaborate on tradeoffs when ACLs are not set. How will the published site be different with this setting? Are additional compensation staps reuquired after publish?

Comment: Ref the above comment: https://blog.winhost.com/how-to-stop-web-deploymsbuild-from-skewing-server-permissions/

Answer (score 5):

First of all unload your project (Right click on project and find unload project)
And then open your .pubxml file and add

```
<IncludeSetACLProviderOnDestination>False</IncludeSetACLProviderOnDestination>
```

under

```
 <PropertyGroup>
```

which should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeSetACLProviderOnDestination>False</IncludeSetACLProviderOnDestination>
```