# Ignore Directory in MSDeploy and MSBuild

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, msdeploy

I have a Web Site project that is deployed using "Publish Web Site" feature in Visual Studio.  I understand this feature uses WebDeploy (MSDeploy) which calls MSBuild to compile the site.

There is a directory within the website that needs to be ignored by both WebDeploy and MSBuild because it breaks the site.

I was able to configure the deployment configuration file (.pubxml) to make WebDeploy ignore directory:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>node_modules</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I was also able to get the site to compile by making the directory hidden in the file system.

However, I am unable to get MSBuild to ignore the directory when called from WebDeploy.

How do I ignore the directory anytime the site is compiled?

**Update**

The compiler logs this in the Output Window when it fails:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.WebSite.Publishing.targets(172,5): Error MSB4018: The "CollectFilesinFolder" task failed unexpectedly.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when called from WebDeplay"? Are you referring to msdeploy.exe?

Comment: I click "Publish Web Site" from the Solution Explorer, it launches Publishing dialog box.  When I click publish, it calls MSDeploy which calls MSBuild.

Comment: Gotcha. For the record, it's actually the other way around: MSBuild calls MSDeploy - MSDeploy has no dependency on MSBuild.

Comment: Ah, ok, good to know. So why does MSBuild work when I click "Build Solution" and fail when I click "Publish Web Site"?

Comment: Because building the project doesn't try to copy the files anywhere. Publishing your project copies the files to a temporary location before packaging/deploying them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to apply a skip rule so that the directory is ignored by the synchronisation process completely.

Add this to your `.pubxml` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipNodeModules">
    <AbsolutePath>node_modules</AbsolutePath>
  </MsDeploySkipRules>
</ItemGroup>
```

If you run into problems with it not working, you may be seeing [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576662/msdeploy-skip-rules-when-using-msbuild-publishprofile-with-visual-studio-2012). If so, just add:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <UseMsDeployExe>true</UseMsDeployExe>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: It still fails when MSBuild is compiling.  The subdirectories in node_modules math the path name too long and it breaks.

Comment: @BillHeitstuman - Exclude node_modules from your project (they'll still exist on the file system)