# Don't delete specific files during asp.net publish?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, deployment

I have a website I'm publishing in Visual Studio. It's publishing using the File System method, and I've selected the option to delete all existing files before publish.

Is there a method that will exclude two specific files from deletion? Both of these files exist in the root of the website folder.

I've tried editing the .pubxml file that is created by Visual Studio to include a "MsDeploySkipRules" option but it never seems to work, no matter what settings I've selected. I've also tried to turn "UsMsDeployExe" on and noticed no difference.

Comment: Readers - see this related SO question regarding MsDeploySkipRules: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12577115/943435

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I don't have the exact answer for what you have asked. 
But there is a work around to achieve what you want. see if this helps

You can include those 2 files into your solution and then set the properties
Build Action = content
Copy to output Directory = Always
This way you will always gets same copies in your publishing directory

Hope this helps!
If you find answer helpful please up vote 
Thanks
Mohan!

Comment: The issue is that I require a unique version of these files for each different website I'm publishing to. The files are already setup for each website, I just want them untouched when I publish.